# How to properly set options for ZXingScannerView?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, zxing, zxing.net

I use Zxing.Net.Mobile in my Xamarin Forms project.

I call ZXingScannerView to the page but scanner options seems to be not working. I set specific type of barcode to scan but it sill scans everything in focus.

I call scannerview at page.xaml:

```
 <zxing:ZXingScannerView x:Name="scanView"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Options="{Binding opts}"
                                        IsScanning="True"
                                        WidthRequest="300"
                                        HeightRequest="600"
                                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

And then define options at xaml.cs

```
public static readonly ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions opts = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
        {
            PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat> { ZXing.BarcodeFormat.AZTEC },
            TryHarder=true
        };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can only bind to public properties.  `opts` is a local field, not a public property.  Try explicitly assigning `opts` to `scanView` in the page constructor.

Comment: @Jason,Yes it helped. Thank you.

Comment: @PavelPolushin Hi, if you have solved that, remember to share your solution as an answer. Then other people will know how to solve that when they have the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jason.
The answer is to assing opts to scanView in the page constructor like this

```
public ScanPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            scanView.Options = opts;
        }
```